# Firebase database: can't download image

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, android-viewholder

I can't download images from my database. I have two child nodes in my database. I am able to fetch the value of Name successfully but there is a problem with downloading the Image. Here is the code of my adapter class:-

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().setQuery(reference,Category.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.img);
            holder.txt.setText(model.getName());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent,false);
            return new MenuViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Model

```
public class Category {
private String Name;
private String Image;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String name, String image) {
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and the content of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to store your image file in Realtime Database. Instead, you can store the image file in Firebase Cloud Storage, and then map it by storing the file/path name in Firebase Database.

Comment: It's being kept as url. There is a storage url in the Image folder. From there you can not pull url... "No setter/field for Image found on class" there is this error in the logcat